# Datatable jquery: how to dynamically change the number of displayed row based on page

Tags: javascript, datatable, pagination, datatables

I have a problem to display dynamically number of row of data in datatable. 
First, i have default number of row in table is 6.

[image: First page]

But when i click the page 2, i want it displays 10 records of data, just like the picture below

[image: second page]

and then when i click the page 3, it displays 5 records, like this

[image]

and so on. 
here is my javascript code, i want this "iDisplayLength" to be dynamically change based on the page

[image]

please help me to solve my problem

Comment: Please, create a JSfiddle demo

Comment: Why would you ever want to make this? It completely defeats the purpose of paginating. Pagination is used to display large numbers of data in pages. If you change the page size when you change pages, you will show some duplicate data and some data will never be shown.